# How to create AngularJS Route with dashes instead of slashes

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-routing

Is it possible to create Angular routes with dashes instead of slashes, and variable content in the URL fragment? For example:

In the Angular phone Tutorial, URLs look like this, e.g:

http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/#/phones/motorola-xoom

this is implemented via a Route Provider such as:

```
  when('/phones/:phoneId', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
    controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
  })
```

what I'd like to do is have URLS that look more like:

http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/#/phones/{{manufacturer}}--{{devicename}}--{{phoneid}}

where {{phoneid}} is a numerical database key and the {{manufacturer}} text will vary from phone to phone. This is because I need the numerical key to drive my database but want the manufacturer & devicename text (or my equivalent) in the URL for seo purposes....

Effectively I'd like to do in Angular Routes what I can do in htaccess files, where I'd do something like:
RewriteRule ^(.*)--by--(.*)--(.*)$  phone.php?mfg=$1&devicename=$2&phoneid=$3

I know Angular routes don't support wildcards like this, but wondering how I might be able achieve an effect somewhat like this. Or maybe there is some extension which enables this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variable using :name in the url ([source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route))

In your config:

```
config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/phones/:manufacturer--:devicename--:phoneid', {
          templateUrl: 'file.html',
          controller: 'PhoneController'
     });
```

To access the parameters in your controller:

```
$routeParams.manufacturer
$routeParams.devicename
$routeParams.phoneid
```

Comment: Genius. That works perfectly. Didn't realize you could put more than one variable in the url. Thank you!